# Installing command line apps

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, terminal

I have an unrooted Samsung Galaxy S4 Active running Android 4.2 Jelly Bean. I have installed the Terminal Emulator and am wondering how to install apps to the command line.

Is it possible for me to install applications such as `alsa-utils` or `cowsay` like you would with a normal Linux machine. At the moment there isn't much you can do with the terminal that's of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a folder which is writable by the ADB user and put ARM binaries there. I recall that /data/local/bin is such a place. Then you can include that folder in the PATH variable.

You can compile your own binaries (I don't know how and even if I did explaining that would probably fill a page or two here) or  grab them online. [Take a look here](http://dan.drown.org/android/), you can find a lot of useful packages.

If you like to play around in the command line, and **you know what you're doing**, you could consider rooting the phone. That would make it possible to install busybox easily into the /system partition, and allow more to play around with in general.